# Shell script to filter date alone from a particular column of a .csv file and save the output in another csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Consider a .csv file which has dates listed in the 6th column in format 
`7/20/2017 17:00` for example.

If I give input as `7/11/2017` then it should filter the column that has the matching input date and the output should be saved in another .csv file

I need a command to filter 6th column  based on input given.

file.csv has below entries:

```
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/21/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/30/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
```

similarly multiple entries that date and time format in 6th column. Input given in runtime like read `7/20/2017`, then it should filter the date from 6th column and save the output entries to another .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with **awk**:

```
awk -F, -v d="7/20/2017" '$6~d' input.csv > dates.csv
```

The `dates.csv` contents:

```
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
```

---

If date value comes from shell variable:

```
d="7/20/2017"
awk -F, -v d="$d" '$6~d' input.csv > dates.csv
```

Comment: the matching column's entire row should be moved to dates.csv. Like if i give input 7/20/2017 then output 
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89 should be saved in dates.csv file

Comment: @user8554534, ok, it's even shorter

Comment: thanks a lot...it works. !!!
Also can you share me the awk command if the date input is given in a variable like date="7/20/2017"

Comment: Like
date="7/20/2017"
Command should be like
awk -F, -v $date '$6~date' input.csv > dates.csv

Comment: don't use `date` as a variable name. It's a built-in function name

Comment: @user8554534, see my additional approach

Comment: I know this thread is old, but what if the filter condition needs to be changed like filter rows which are 12 months older than current date

Comment: @Novice_Techie, In that case, you would need to 1) set the current date in correspondent format into variable `-v d=<current date>`; 2) split the 6th field by space to get the date part only; 3) compare the dates. Check the following topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948321/3185459

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one column with a date in that format:

```
$ grep -F '7/20/2017' file.csv
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
```

You may redirect that to a new file:

```
$ grep -F '7/20/2017' file.csv >new.csv
```

To properly parse a CSV file, use a CSV parser, like the one built into [the CSVkit tools](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvgrep -c 6 -m '7/20/2017' file.csv
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
23,54,one,tree,56,7/20/2017 17:00,23,iii,89
```